# Reference directive attribute with vm rather than $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a custom directive that looks like this:

```
<my-queue id="report.id" version="report.version"></my-queue>
```

In my directive definition object I reference my controller and scope like so:

```
controller: 'QueueController',
controllerAs: 'myQueue',
scope: {
  id: '=',
  version: '='
}
```

In my controller I set `var vm = this` so I can refer to scope variables as `vm.variable`. However this does not work for `id` and `version`. I've found that I need to inject `$scope` and reference these properties as `$scope.id` and `$scope.version`.
Is there a way to set this up so that I can avoid injecting `$scope` and stay consistent with the rest of my controller by referencing `vm.id` and `vm.version`?

Comment: No.  Creating an isolate scope like you have is the proper way to handle this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The controllerAs property on your directive config object will be what you use to refer to your controller instance, so if you want to use `vm` in your template, you will need to set the `controllerAs` property to `vm`.  Also, by setting the `bindToController` property to `true` you can bind directly to the view model instead of $scope:

```
function myQueue() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: ... ,
        controller: myQueueCtrl,
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        scope: {
            id: '=',
            version: '='
        },
        bindToController: true
    }
}
```

With your current directive configuration, your `controllerAs` reference will be under `myQueue`, not `vm`, meaning any properties you create on your `vm` (e.g. `vm.id`) in your controller will be on `myQueue` in your template (e.g. `myQueue.id`).

By adding `bindToController` we do not need to inject $scope in the directive's controller:

```
function QueueController() {
    var vm = this;
}
```

Then you can refer to your vars in the directive template as

```
{{vm.id}}
{{vm.version}}
```

There is a plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/tR2zOc?p=preview) of your directive with `bindToController` set to true, and `controllerAs` set to `vm`.